# Modular Arithmetic: Least Non-negative Residues

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am to compute the least non-negative residue of $4^n \pmod{9}$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, \dots$
I must also prove that $6 · 4^n ≡ 6 \pmod{9}$ for every $n > 0$.

Comment: I calculated these values for those $n$ I mentioned, but does that really suffice?

Answer (score 3):

- $4^1=4;\ \ 4^2=16\equiv 7\equiv -2; \ \ 4^3\equiv 4\cdot(-2)=-8\equiv 1 \pmod9$. Then it's periodic, $4^4\equiv 4$ again, $4^5=4^2\cdot 4^3\equiv 4^2$, and so on..
- For the other one, use that $a\equiv b\pmod{m} \implies ka\equiv kb\pmod{km}$.

Comment: Yes, but what can I do with this last part?

Comment: $4^n\equiv 1^n=1\pmod{3} \implies 3\cdot 4^n\equiv3\pmod{9} \implies 6\cdot 4^n\equiv6\pmod{9}$.